# Fine-tuning pre-trained Word2Vec model with Gensim 4.0

Tags: gensim, word2vec, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

With Gensim < 4.0, we can retrain a word2vec model using the following code:

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", binary=True)
model.train(my_corpus, total_examples=len(my_corpus), epochs=model.epochs)
```

However, what I understand is that Gensim 4.0 is no longer supporting `Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format`. Instead, I can only load the keyedVectors.

How to fine-tune a pre-trained word2vec model (such as the model trained on GoogleNews) with my domain-specific corpus using Gensim 4.0?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think that code would've ever have worked in Gensim versions before 4.0. A plain list-of-word-vectors, like `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin`, does not (& never has) had enough info to continue training.

It's missing the hidden-to-output layer weights & word-frequency info essential for training.

Looking at past source code, as of release 1.0.0 (February 2017), that code wouldn've already given a [deprecation-error with a pointer to the method for loading a plain set-of-word-vectors](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/1.0.0/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L1304) - to address people with the mistaken notion that could work – and [raised other errors on any attempts to `train()` such a model](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/1.0.0/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L792). (Pre-1.0.0, docs also [warned that this would not work](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/0.13.4.1/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L1137), & would have failed with a less-helpful error.)

As one of those errors mentioned, there has at times been experimental support for loading *some* of a prior set-of-word-vectors to clobber any words in an existing model's already-initialized vocabulary, via `.intersect_word2vec_format()`. But by default that both (1) locks the imported vectors against further change; (2) brings in no new words. That's unlike what people most often want from "fine-tuning", so it's not a ready-made help for that goal.

I believe some people have cobbled together custom code to achieve various kinds of fine-tuning in their projects – but I don't know of anyone who's published a reliable recipe or strong results. (And I suspect some of the people who *think* they're doing this well just haven't rigorously evaluated the steps they are taking.)

If you have any recipe you know worked pre-Gensim-4.0.0, it should be adaptable - 4.0 changes to the `Word2Vec`-related classes were mainly refactorings, optimizations, & new options (with little-to-none removal of functionality). But a reliable description of what used-to-work, or which particular fine-tuning strategy is being pursued for what specific benefits, to make more specific recommendations.

Comment: Thanks @gojomo ! this is a very helpful answer. So what does `.intersect_word2vec_format()` do if it does not change the vectors or handle new words as you mentioned? As per the [documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/gensim.models.Word2Vec.intersect_word2vec_format.html), setting lockf to 1 will enable updating the vectors.

Comment: Yes, you can use that (non-default) option to let 'imported' vectors adjust, too. Normally, it only changes your *unique* words, and by holdin imported words constant, the intended effect was to situate your *new* words into a space compatible with the unchanged old ones. If both old & new are changing, there's a more risk that all your trained words may be nudged to an new arrangement that's drifted out of compatibility with the original vector source -  more potential complication to control. But in neither case, is the resulting vocabulary *enlarged* by the `intersect` operation.

Comment: (Separately, I think there's I'e seen another bug to work around in `.intersect_word2vec_format()` in Gensim-4.0.0+ - but as a seldom-used/limited/experimental feature, it's not strongly spported. If you think with its limits it could still meet your needs, you try it, and hit an error, I can try to provide a workaround/patch.)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your detailed answer.